# Not able to run Spring Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I'm getting this exception while starting my spring application

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/ToStringSerializerBase
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:821) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:719) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:642) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:600) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3138) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3343) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2554) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 69 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ToStringSerializerBase
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 83 common frames omitted
```

I tried adding jackson dependency but it didn't work

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: 1. People faced this kind of error with 2.9.4 or older version. Just use the newer version like the latest one 2.12.0 and try. OR 2. If you are using springboot then jackson is added by default, So the version of jackson you are adding manually is probably conflicting with the one spring boot adds,  delete the jackson dependencies from your pom and try.
If you need to override the version spring boots add, then you need to exclude it first and then add your own.